# Send user back to first page?

Tags: vba, ms-word

So, after running the code bellow, i want to send users back to the top of the first page. Tried to use `Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory` and the `GoTo` metod, but nothing seen to work properly.

Now, after the code runs, the user is always back to the end of the first page.

Some clue on why is this happening?

This is the code.

```
Private Sub OptionButton5_Click()
'Orange
Dim sShapes As Shape
Dim Orange
Dim Green
Dim DarkOrange
Dim DarkGreen
Dim White

DarkOrange = RGB(252, 138, 74)
Orange = RGB(253, 189, 153)
Green = RGB(70, 184, 160)
DarkGreen = RGB(28, 76, 66)
White = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



If OptionButton5.Value = True Then
If MsgBox("Deseja mudar para Santa Lucia?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Isso pode levar algum tempo", vbYesNo, "Mudança de Modelo") = vbYes Then
    GoTo Label2
   Else
   GoTo Label1
   End If
   
   
Label2:
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TabelaConta").Select
    Selection.Tables(1).Style = "Tabela de Grade 2 - Ênfase 2"
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ListaEspecie").Select
    Selection.Style = "Tabela de Grade 2 - Ênfase 2"
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ListaEspecie").Range.Rows.LeftIndent = -37.15
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 1

    
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("santa").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ultrafarma").Range.Font.Hidden = True
End If

     For Each sShapes In ActiveDocument.Shapes
   
            If InStr(sShapes.Name, "Rectangle") Then
            sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = DarkOrange

            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "TagAmarelaEscura") Then
            sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = DarkOrange


            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "TagAmarelaClara") Then
            sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Orange

            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "LinhaGrossa") Then
            sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Orange

            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "Quad") Then
            sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Orange

            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "BolaCor") Then
            sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Green

            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "Reta") Then
            sShapes.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Green

            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "Titulo") Then
            sShapes.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            sShapes.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = White

            ElseIf InStr(sShapes.Name, "Oval") Then
            sShapes.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = DarkGreen
        End If
        Next sShapes
        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory


Label1:

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to select something to apply a style. Stop using `Selection` in your code and you’ll have no need to return the user anywhere.

Comment: Thx Sir. That was was the problem.